# custom admin page - list_filter by first letter

Tags: django, django-admin

I have class for customize admin subpage:

```
class SerchPlaceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = ('nameplace',)
```

The `nameplace` is `models.CharField`. I want to filter records by first letter. Pleas look at printscree[image]n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work for you, see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter) for more info:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class FirstLetterListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('First letter')

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'letter'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
            ('A', _('A')),
            ('B', _('B'))
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        return queryset.filter(nameplace__startswith=self.value())

class SerchPlaceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter = (FirstLetterListFilter,)
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer had an issue for me: it would break the non-filtered view. This is fixed by the `if`-clause in the `queryset` method below.

Also, the below code searches case insensitive, and only shows the letters that do return results, including the count.

```
class FirstLetterFilter(SimpleListFilter):
    # Human-readable title which will be displayed in the
    # right admin sidebar just above the filter options.
    title = 'First Letter'

    # Parameter for the filter that will be used in the URL query.
    parameter_name = 'letter'
    letters = list(string.ascii_uppercase)

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        qs = model_admin.get_queryset(request)
        lookups = []
        for letter in self.letters:
            count = qs.filter(name__istartswith=letter).count()
            if count:
                lookups.append((letter, '{} ({})'.format(letter, count)))
        return lookups

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        """
        Returns the filtered queryset based on the value
        provided in the query string and retrievable via
        `self.value()`.
        """
        filter_val = self.value()
        if filter_val in self.letters:
            return queryset.filter(name__istartswith=self.value())
```

Of course, for huge tables, I'd recommend to extract the first letter into its own column and put an index (case insensitive) on it.

For case insensitive ordering which would fit well with the case insensitive search add this to your ModelAdmin:

```
class MyModelAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name',)
    search_fields = ['name']

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return [Lower('name')]
```